# Efficient Firebase Storage image download

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm developing a Flutter app and I don't know which is the best way to store and retrieve an image from Firebase Storage.

For example, I'm implementing a show profile picture feature:

```
CircleAvatar(backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profilePictureUrl))
```

I get `profilePictureUrl` from my database. I can save its value on database in two way: saving its firebase download url, or saving its firebase path.

**Case 1: saving firebase download url**

With `getDownloadUrl` I get this kind of url:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{project}/o/{path}?alt=media&token={token}
```

If I save it on my database I would persist an Url with a token inside. Do you think that this token will expire sooner or later?

**Case 2: saving firebase image path**

If I save the image path on my database than I have the overhead of calling `getDownloadUrl` before any image access, for example:

Firebase Storage path value: images/users/{userId}/profile

```
  Future<String> getProfilePictureUrl(String path) async {
    var ref = _firebaseStorage.ref().child(path);
    String url = (await ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
    return url.toString();
  }
```

**Dilemma**

What is the best practice to handle the images upload and download with Firebase storage?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have some code that you tried already, and that you could show us ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 1 - The download URL will remain valid until you manually revoke it in the console; i.e. it doesn't just expire. See [Revoking Firebase storage download urls](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aw86jf8b7PY). The URL is considered 'unguessable'. Revocation exists so that you can change it if it ever became compromised.

Case 2 - You will receive the same URL every time (the same one which you can inspect in the Console) - unless, of course, someone has manually revoked it in the console and created a new one.